# Push video stream to another machine

Tags: linux, python-3.x, rtsp

I have received camera video and successfully​ processed video ( outlined box on the objects using tensorflow). I  want to retransmit the processed video to my client machine , so that I can show the processed video at client  in real time.

I googled a lot but couldn't find the solution. I am doing programming in python , is there any library for RTSP in Linux which I can import in python3. Or any other protocol which can stream out the video to another machine.

Comment: looks like this is a job for ffmpeg and its suite.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anthony I tried Ffmpeg , for this in installed pip3 install python-ffmpeg for Python3 dependency.

```
command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
               '-y',
               '-f', 'rawvideo',
               '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
               '-s', dimension,
               '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
               '-r', '24',
               '-i', '-',
               '-an',
               '-tune', 'zerolatency',
               '-preset', 'ultrafast',
               '-crf', '0',
               '-b:v', '2000k',
               '-qmin', '1',
               '-qmax', '4',
               '-qscale', '4',
               '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
               feed]

self.proc = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=None, stdin=sp.PIPE)

while True:

  ret, frame = self.cap.read()
  #some analysis done here
  if ret:
     self.proc.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
```

output vcodec may be anytype.

For that to work create ffserver.conf file in /etc/ffserver.conf like this-

```
HTTPPort 1234
RTSPPort 1235

MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000


<Feed feed1.ffm>
        File /tmp/feed1.ffm
        ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>
<Stream test1.sdp>
    NoDefaults
    Feed feed1.ffm
    Format rtp
    Noaudio
    VideoCodec libx264
    VideoSize 1920x1080
    #VideoHighQuality
    VideoBitRate 64
    VideoFrameRate 17
    VideoGopSize 25
    VideoBufferSize 50000   
    AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
    AVOptionVideo me_range 16
    AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
    AVOptionVideo qmin 30
    AVOptionVideo qmax 34
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
    PreRoll 0
</Stream>
```

And run ffserver